# How do I use 1 function to add different images to numerous containers using File Picker package?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, filepicker

I'd like to add 2 different images to 2 different containers using 1 function on my Flutter web app. I want to pass the same 'Select File' function on both container buttons. I want to make the code as clean as possible so want to avoid duplicating variables and functions where necessary. Can you please let me know how I can reduce this code.

```
 `PlatformFile? pickedFile;
  PlatformFile? pickedFile2;

  Uint8List? selectedImageInBytes;
  Uint8List? selectedImageInBytes2;

  Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result == null) return;

    setState(() {
      pickedFile = result.files.first;
      selectedImageInBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
    });
  }

  Future selectFile2() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result == null) return;

    setState(() {
      pickedFile2 = result.files.first;
      selectedImageInBytes2 = result.files.first.bytes;
    });
  }

    ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue, elevation: 0.0),
                    onPressed: selectFile,
                    child: const Text('Select File',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ),

    ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue, elevation: 0.0),
                    onPressed: selectFile,
                    child: const Text('Select File',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ),`
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it won't reduce it a lot, but you can make a verification passing 1 or 2 as a parameter to know which container it is about, something like:

```
Future selectFile(int containerNumber) async {
  final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
  if (result == null) return;

  setState(() {
    if (containerNumber == 1) {
      pickedFile = result.files.first;
      selectedImageInBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
    } else if (containerNumber == 2) {
      pickedFile2 = result.files.first;
      selectedImageInBytes2 = result.files.first.bytes;
    }
  });
}

// In your widget build method:

ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  onPressed: () => selectFile(1), // Pass 1 to indicate the first container
  child: const Text(
    'Select File 1',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
),

ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  onPressed: () => selectFile(2), // Pass 2 to indicate the second container
  child: const Text(
    'Select File 2',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
),
```

Comment: It is possible to reduce the 2 PlatformFile variables to just 1 variable? I have tried, although am getting an 'unexpected null value' error. I need to keep the variable outside the function as I am passing it in another uploadFile function, which uploads the image to Firebase Storage